# Trying to set the value of an input to original value using Escape key

Tags: javascript

I've build this inline edit component and am nearing the finish line, but can't seems to figure out this last bit.

I'd like to capture the original value of the input, so that if a user hits the ESC key, it reverts back to the original "Lorem ipsum". That would be in the noEdit() function.

Code below, but here is a link to the pen: https://codepen.io/sfilippone/pen/rNmEKXd

HTML:

```
    <div class="c-inline-edit--icons">
        <div id="inline-edit-wrapper-1" class="c-inline-edit-wrapper">
            <input id="inline-edit-input-1" class="c-readonly-input c-input--default" type="text" value="Lorem ipsum" onclick="yesEdit(1)" readonly/>
            <a id="btn-edit-1" class="btn-icon-edit" onclick="yesEdit(1)"><span class="icon icon-16-edit-default-mono"></span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="c-btn-set-icon large">
            <a id="btn-cancel-1" class="btn-icon c-btn-secondary" onclick="noEdit(1)"><span class="icon-24-close-mono"></span></a>
            <a id="btn-save-1" class="btn-icon c-btn-primary" onclick="noEdit(1)"><span class="icon-24-checkmark-mono"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 function yesEdit(idNo) {
  document.getElementById("btn-edit-" + idNo).style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("btn-save-" + idNo).style.display = "inline-block";
  document.getElementById("btn-cancel-" + idNo).style.display = "inline-block";

  var element = document.getElementById("inline-edit-input-" + idNo);
  element.removeAttribute("readonly");
  element.classList.replace("c-readonly-input", "c-input");
}

function noEdit(idNo) {
  document.getElementById("btn-edit-" + idNo).style.display = "inline-block";
  document.getElementById("btn-save-" + idNo).style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("btn-cancel-" + idNo).style.display = "none";

  var element = document.getElementById("inline-edit-input-" + idNo);
// HERE IS MY ISSUE
            var originalContent = element.value;
            var element.value = originalContent;
  element.setAttribute("readonly", "");
  element.classList.replace("c-input", "c-readonly-input");
}

var inline1 = document.getElementById("inline-edit-input-1");

inline1.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.key === "Escape") {
    noEdit(1);
  } else if (event.key === "Enter") {
    yesEdit(1);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`element.value` is the current value, not the original value. The original value is in `element.defaultValue` or `element.getAttribute("value")`

So use

```
element.value = element.defaultValue;
```

to reset it.

Comment: Thanks will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the original value as a global variable that is updated each time the user saves an edit.

```
let originalVal;
function yesEdit(idNo) {
  document.getElementById("btn-edit-" + idNo).style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("btn-save-" + idNo).style.display = "inline-block";
  document.getElementById("btn-cancel-" + idNo).style.display = "inline-block";

  var element = document.getElementById("inline-edit-input-" + idNo);
  element.removeAttribute("readonly");
  originalVal = element.value;
  element.classList.replace("c-readonly-input", "c-input");
}

function noEdit(idNo) {
  document.getElementById("btn-edit-" + idNo).style.display = "inline-block";
  document.getElementById("btn-save-" + idNo).style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("btn-cancel-" + idNo).style.display = "none";

  var element = document.getElementById("inline-edit-input-" + idNo);
  element.setAttribute("readonly", "");
  element.classList.replace("c-input", "c-readonly-input");
}

var inline1 = document.getElementById("inline-edit-input-1");

inline1.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.key === "Escape") {
    noEdit(1);
    document.getElementById("inline-edit-input-1").value = originalVal;
  } else if (event.key === "Enter") {
    yesEdit(1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a shot.